# WIX CustomAction that runs when install fails

Tags: wix

I have a simple Wix project and I want to add the custom action that will run no matter what the result of the install is - success, error, cancel etc.
I've tried CustomAction with `Execute="rollback"` - it doesn't seem working.
In order to check if my custom actions are called on error I've added this custom action to generate an error (it returns `ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE` from the DLL):

```
<CustomAction Id="TestBad" BinaryKey="testDll" DllEntry="TestBad" HideTarget="yes" Impersonate="no" Execute="immediate" Return="check"/>
```

and didn't find even one way to call the custom action on error.
Is there any way to do this?

**EDIT**

I've forgot to mention that I need it to run at the end of install process - I want to know the result of the installation process.

Comment: Can't you just run you custom action when setup starts then (maybe even before the UI is shown)?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mention the very important part - I need to know the result of the install process - success or fail. So I need this custom action to run at the end of install.

Comment: I don't know how to do that from a custom action. Maybe you could consider using a bootstraper (wrapping application) instead? I.e. start your installer from another program, and then check exit code?

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to avoid it but it seems like I need to use that approach.

Comment: [EmbeddedUI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc542588(v=vs.85).aspx) might help. I haven't used it but it appears you can ("get to") write code to drive a WiX-defined UI from it as well as receive event notifications throughout the lifecycle.